# Redirect URLs without trailing slash to a different domain with trailing slash in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to redirect URLs that don't end with trailing slashes to URLs with the same path on a different domain but ending with trailing slashes.

For example:

```
 origin.example.com\my-awesome-post  -> example.com\my-awesome-post\  - redirect
 origin.example.com\my-awesome-post\ - shouldn't be redirected
```

My current .htaccess configuration doesn't work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} origin.example.com\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ http://example.com/%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any advice how can I achieve this with .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RewriteCond` has wrong regex pattern, use this rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^.]+$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =origin.example.com
  RewriteRule [^/]$ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```